# How to add space between two paragraph import from csv file through powershell script

Tags: powershell-extensions

We have a field under .csv file and that field contain two paragraphs showing in one row :

```
orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 

It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
```

When we are try to insert this data from Sitecore powershell script then it does not add space between two paragraph in Rich text box.

Adding code in powershell script

```
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()            
  $item["Description"] = $row.'Description'
  $item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You text contains multiple lines, but it doesn't matter when html is being rendered.

What you need to do is either wrap every single line into a separate paragraph (`<p>`) or replace new lines with `<br>` tags.

Here is sample code for the latter:

```
  $item["Description"] = ($row.'Description' -replace "`r`n", '<br>') -replace "`n", '<br>'
```

I don't know if it's both `CR` + `LF` characters or just `LF` so I wrote a code which should take care of both situations ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CRLF ).

If you want to wrap your text in paragraphs, you need to add `<p>` before and `</p>` after your string and replace every line ending with `</p><p>` (assuming that your input is not html code already).